# Whats wrong in my jQuery function?? Trying to use buttons for rating

Tags: html, jquery

here i have my jQuery function to select buttons, if i just use a function in conjunction with a selection ( comment part1 - part 1 end) my code works great.

But in conjunction with the second function / html part 2 my code no longer works properly!

Where is the error?

Here you can see the issue, i can select in the first row, but when i want to select another value in second row the selection in first row is deselected/disabled.

in summary i can only select a value in one row

[image: See here]

```
<script> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        
      $(".btnrating").on('click',(function(e) {
      
      var previous_value = $("#selected_rating").val();
      
      var selected_value = $(this).attr("data-attr");
      $("#selected_rating").val(selected_value);
      
      $(".selected-rating").empty();
      $(".selected-rating").html(selected_value);
      
      for (i = 1; i <= selected_value; ++i) {
      $("#rating-star-"+i).toggleClass('btn-warning');
      $("#rating-star-"+i).toggleClass('btn-default');
      }
      
      for (ix = 1; ix <= previous_value; ++ix) {
      $("#rating-star-"+ix).toggleClass('btn-warning');
      $("#rating-star-"+ix).toggleClass('btn-default');
      }
      }));
    });

    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

   $(".btnrating").on('click',(function(f) {
      
    var previous_value = $("#selected_heart").val();
      
    var selected_value = $(this).attr("data-heart");
    $("#selected_heart").val(selected_value);
      
    $(".selected-heart").empty();
    $(".selected-heart").html(selected_value);
      
    for (i = 1; i <= selected_value; ++i) {
    $("#rating-heart-"+i).toggleClass('btn-warning');
    $("#rating-heart-"+i).toggleClass('btn-default');
    }
      
    for (ix = 1; ix <= previous_value; ++ix) {
    $("#rating-heart-"+ix).toggleClass('btn-warning');
    $("#rating-heart-"+ix).toggleClass('btn-default');
    }
      
    }));
    });
</script>
```

This is my HTML:
Part 1 works fine alone.

```
<!-- Part 1 Start -->
<div class="form-group" id="rating-ability-wrapper">
        <label class="control-label" for="rating">
        <input type="hidden" id="selected_rating" name="selected_rating" value="" required="required">
        </label>
        <h2 class="bold rating-header" style="">
        <h4>How did you like the food?</h4>
        </h2>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-attr="1" id="rating-star-1">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-attr="2" id="rating-star-2">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-attr="3" id="rating-star-3">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-attr="4" id="rating-star-4">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-attr="5" id="rating-star-5">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      <span class="selected-rating">0</span><small> / 5</small>
    </div>
  <!-- Part 1 End -->


  <!-- Part 2 Start -->
  <div class="form-group" id="rating-ability-wrapper">
        <label class="control-label" for="rating">
        <input type="hidden" id="selected_heart" name="selected_heart" value="" required="required">
        </label>
        <h2 class="bold rating-header" style="">
        <h4>how satisfied were you with the food?</h4>
        </h2>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-heart="1" id="rating-heart-1">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-heart="2" id="rating-heart-2">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-heart="3" id="rating-heart-3">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-heart="4" id="rating-heart-4">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-heart="5" id="rating-heart-5">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      <span class="selected-heart">0</span><small> / 5</small>
    </div>
  <!-- Part 2 End -->
```

Comment: You have two elements with `id="rating-ability-wrapper"` which is invalid HTML.

Comment: @kmoser What is the correct id

Comment: @kmoser so i gave another id, but same issue again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your heart rating buttons had a class of `.btnrating` when they should be `.btnheart`.

You also had two calls to `jQuery(document).ready()` when only one was necessary.

This code should work now:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".btnrating").on('click',function(e) {
        var previous_value = $("#selected_rating").val();
        var selected_value = $(this).attr("data-attr");
        $("#selected_rating").val(selected_value);
      
        $(".selected-rating").empty();
        $(".selected-rating").html(selected_value);
      
        for (i = 1; i <= selected_value; ++i) {
            $("#rating-star-"+i).toggleClass('btn-warning');
            $("#rating-star-"+i).toggleClass('btn-default');
        }
      
        for (ix = 1; ix <= previous_value; ++ix) {
            $("#rating-star-"+ix).toggleClass('btn-warning');
            $("#rating-star-"+ix).toggleClass('btn-default');
        }
    });

    $(".btnheart").on('click',function(f) {
        var previous_value = $("#selected_heart").val();
      
        var selected_value = $(this).attr("data-heart");
        $("#selected_heart").val(selected_value);
      
        $(".selected-heart").empty();
        $(".selected-heart").html(selected_value);
      
        for (i = 1; i <= selected_value; ++i) {
            $("#rating-heart-"+i).toggleClass('btn-warning');
            $("#rating-heart-"+i).toggleClass('btn-default');
        }
      
        for (ix = 1; ix <= previous_value; ++ix) {
            $("#rating-heart-"+ix).toggleClass('btn-warning');
            $("#rating-heart-"+ix).toggleClass('btn-default');
        }
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Part 1 Start -->
<div class="form-group" id="rating-ability-wrapper">
        <label class="control-label" for="rating">
        <input type="hidden" id="selected_rating" name="selected_rating" value="" required="required">
        </label>
        <h2 class="bold rating-header" style="">
        <h4>How did you like the food?</h4>
        </h2>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-attr="1" id="rating-star-1">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-attr="2" id="rating-star-2">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-attr="3" id="rating-star-3">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-attr="4" id="rating-star-4">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnrating btn btn-default btn-lg" data-attr="5" id="rating-star-5">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      <span class="selected-rating">0</span><small> / 5</small>
    </div>
  <!-- Part 1 End -->


  <!-- Part 2 Start -->
  <div class="form-group" id="rating-ability-wrapper">
        <label class="control-label" for="rating">
        <input type="hidden" id="selected_heart" name="selected_heart" value="" required="required">
        </label>
        <h2 class="bold rating-header" style="">
        <h4>how satisfied were you with the food?</h4>
        </h2>
        <button type="button" class="btnheart btn btn-default btn-lg" data-heart="1" id="rating-heart-1">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnheart btn btn-default btn-lg" data-heart="2" id="rating-heart-2">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnheart btn btn-default btn-lg" data-heart="3" id="rating-heart-3">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnheart btn btn-default btn-lg" data-heart="4" id="rating-heart-4">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnheart btn btn-default btn-lg" data-heart="5" id="rating-heart-5">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      <span class="selected-heart">0</span><small> / 5</small>
    </div>
  <!-- Part 2 End -->
```